# How can I create a function that uses a period. for instance; ".isdigit()" or ".append()"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

I want to know how to be able to create a function that you can call on by attaching it to something else

for example `.isdigit()` has a period at the beginning and returns a `1` or `0` depending on if the variable is a number.

How can I do something similar, for instance: `string.myfunc()`?

Comment: Create a class and add methods inside the class. Call the method on the object of the class

Comment: You have to know the class (object-oriented programming) concept first, before you can fully understand a function that uses a period. Simply put, a function that uses a period is a function that applies to the variable in front of the period. For instance, str.append() does the append operation onto the object str.

Comment: Why specifically do you want to do this?

Comment: You need to learn about `methods`. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-method-and-function-in-python or similar.

Comment: You are better off to define a global function, that is, def myfun(str), and use it by myfunc(str) instead of str.myfunc(). in case you want string.myfunc(). This is kinda impossible. The string class is predefined; you can't write a method "myfunc()" for the string class.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `class`. For this example, `.myfunc()` will return `1` if the number is greater than `0`, otherwise, it will return `0`:

```
class s:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def myfunc(self):
        if self.value > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

num = s(20)

print(num.myfunc())
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.func()` is specially used for objects belonging to a particular class.
 For example, `.split()` is specially built for strings.

You can also create them by creating a `class` and then defining a function in that class.